# How to get eslint to validate Adobe Extendscript (.jsx) files in VSCode

Tags: javascript, eslint, visual-studio-code, extendscript

I'm trying to write extendscript scripts for Adobe After Effects, using VSCode. I'd like to get some linting happening (not too fussed if it's ESLint or any other linter), but I can't convince ESLint to lint my files.

Extendscript is a dialect of the ECMAScript standard and therefore similar to JavaScript and ActionScript. The files have the extension `.jsx`. There are some extendscript plugins for VSCode, [this one](https://github.com/Hennamann/ExtendScript-for-Visual-Studio-Code) provides language support, so that VSCode sees my .jsx files as extendscript files. So I was hoping that this would work in my `settings.json`:

```
{
  "eslint.options": {
    "extensions":  [".jsx", ".js"]
  },
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "extendscript"
  ]
}
```

If I try the command ESLint.ShowOutputChannel I get the error:

> ESLint is not running. By default only JavaScript files are validated. If you want to validate other file types please specify them in the 'eslint.validate' setting.

**edit** I also tried replacing `"extendscript"`  in line 10 with

```
{ "language": "extendscript", "autofix": false }
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
{
  "eslint.options": {
    "extensions":  [".jsx", ".js"]
  },
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "jsx"
  ]
}
```

Looking on the [github repo for the Extendscript Language](https://github.com/Hennamann/ExtendScript-for-Visual-Studio-Code/blob/master/syntaxes/jsx.tmLanguage), I've found out that the language id is registered as jsx, instead of extendscript.

Comment: Brilliant! That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your user/workspace settings are OK. Maybe you are missing having installed ESLint?

If you are working on a workspace, you should have installed `eslint` in your `package.json`

```sh
npm i -D eslint babel-eslint
```

If you just want VS Code lint always your files, you can install `eslint` as global package:

```sh
npm i -g eslint babel-eslint
```

After that, you should initialize `eslint`

```sh
eslint --init
```

See more examples and documentation for [`eslint` cli](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface)

Comment: I definitely have ESLint installed, I've done eslint --init and I can call eslint from the command line.

Comment: @stib Try putting this in your `settings.json`: `"eslint.enable": true`,
`"javascript.validate.enable": false`